# Dynamically join pivoted table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Maybe the community could advise me on this Postgres question (PostgreSQL 9.5)

There is a big (1.5 mil rows) flightlog table with columns: action type (4 action types), timestamp and user_id.
The users table has 6K rows.

```
**flightlog**
user_id, time, action
2301    "2016-10-25 14:13:25.74668" "View"
8   "2016-04-25 15:02:13.916204"    "Download"
8   "2016-04-25 15:01:20.553475"    "Download"
8   "2016-04-25 14:57:02.430493"    "Download"
8   "2016-04-25 14:57:02.160002"    "Download"
8   "2016-04-25 14:57:01.397602"    "Download"
26  "2016-10-25 16:01:25.005285"    "View"
216 "2016-10-24 14:46:16.035242"    "View"
2182    "2016-10-24 14:47:43.713"   "View"
243 "2016-10-24 12:10:12.187181"    "View"
26  "2016-10-24 15:01:26.269981"    "View"
26  "2016-10-24 15:01:28.122361"    "View"

**users**
user_id, email
8 "ndoe@mysite.com"
26  "jdoe@mysite.com"
2301 "kdoe@mysite.com"

**subscriptions**
user_id, expires
8    "2017-08-30 15:48:06.827258"
26   "2017-08-10 00:00:00"
2301 "2017-09-28 09:09:17.56549"
```

I need to have a table with counts for 4 different actions per month for a user,
so it would be user and then 4 actions per month and this is replicated 12 times.
The columns would look the following:

```
user1  period1_action1 period1_action2 period1_action3 period1_action4 period2_action1 etc
```

**To make it more complicated these 12 months should be dynamic for every user, calculated as +12 months from their subscription date in subscriptions table(10K).**

So far I could come with a FILTER-based pivot on actions and join it with cte choosing username and start of the subscription.

```
with counters ( <doing counts using windowing functions>),
     pivot1   ( <pivoting counters using FILTER>
              ...sum(times) filter (where action = 'action1')...
              ),
     recent_subscription (<picking latest subscription for a user>),
     titles   (<using previous cte and adding more info from info table>)

select t.user, t.id, t.subscription_starts, t.expires_at, t.title, email,
                p."action1", p."action2", p."action3 ", p."action4"
      from titles t
      join pivot1 p
...
```

Which correctly produces activity data of 12 months for a user in the following format:

```
user1 ... 1st_period_4user1 action1 action2 action3 action4
user1 ... 2nd_period_4user1 action1 action2 action3 action4
user2 ... 1st_period_4user2 action1 action2 action3 action4
user2 ... 2nd_period_4user2 action1 action2 action3 action4
user3 ... 1st_period_4user3 action1 action2 action3 action4
user3 ... 2nd_period_4user3 action1 action2 action3 action4
```

etc

But the challenge is now to pivot this again to get 12periods/4actions combinations.
Could be just 12 if as below done 
with json_object_aggr as (period: and then 4 actions)

```
 --using the piece above as another CTE called merged 
 --this code does not work :(
select 
        email, id, ends, subs, info, 
        json_object_aggr(starts, s1,v1,p1,d1 ORDER BY starts) as P1,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s2,v2,p2,d2 ORDER BY starts) as P2,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s3,v3,p3,d3 ORDER BY starts) as P3,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s4,v4,p4,d4 ORDER BY starts) as P4,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s5,v5,p5,d5 ORDER BY starts) as P5,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s6,v6,p6,d6 ORDER BY starts) as P6,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s7,v7,p7,d7 ORDER BY starts) as P7,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s8,v8,p8,d8 ORDER BY starts) as P8,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s9,v9,p9,d9 ORDER BY starts) as P9,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s10,v10,p10,d10 ORDER BY starts) as P10,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s11,v11,p11,d11 ORDER BY starts) as P11,
        json_object_aggr(starts, s12,v12,p12,d12 ORDER BY starts) as P12
    from 
            (select email, id,  starts, ends, subs, info, starts, 
  sum("action1") as s1,sum("action2") as v1,sum("action3") as 
  p1,sum("action4") 
  as d1 
              from merged
              group by email, id,  starts, ends, subs, info, starts

            ) m
    group by email, id,  starts, ends, subs, info
    order by email, id,  starts, ends, subs, info
```

Could this be json_object_agg for 4 actions per period?
Could I get help on how to pivot this?

Thank you.

Comment: I find crosstabs a lot easier to use **without** that function. Just use conditional aggregation `count(..) filter (...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, redone that with filter... now need to pivot this again somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you cannot use a series of `CASE` conditionals that result in either 1 or 0 and then `SUM()` them? It would make this process much simpler.

```
WITH subs AS (
      SELECT s.user_id, u.email, MAX(s.sub_date) AS recent_sub_date 
      FROM subscriptions s 
      JOIN users u ON s.userid = u.user_id
      GROUP BY s.user_id, u.email
)
SELECT s.user_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action1' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '1 month' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period1_action1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action2' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '1 month' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period1_action2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action3' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '1 month' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period1_action3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action4' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '1 month' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period1_action4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action1' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '2 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period2_action1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action2' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '2 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period2_action2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action3' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '2 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period2_action3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.action = 'action4' AND f.time <= s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '2 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS period2_action4,
       ...
FROM flightlog f
JOIN subs s ON s.user_id = f.user_id 
WHERE f.time > s.recent_sub_date
AND f.time <= DATE_TRUNC('month', s.recent_sub_date + INTERVAL '13 months') -- end of the 12 months after sub
GROUP BY s.user_id;
```

NOTE: If you do not have indexes on your dates this will probably be pretty slow no matter how you write the query.

Comment: I will check again and get back to you

Comment: I like your approach but for some reason I could not make it work for me with probably time comparison yielding incorrect results. https://imgur.com/a/iCHBN72 this is what I have. https://imgur.com/a/5ZNlJTG this is what is calculated per your script for a definite user. Given the start period, I would expect views come on period 1 and 3 or 2 and 4 depending on setting in interval + month. But based on your script I have 1 and 2 and 3 and on... so something is wrong here logically...

Comment: I could get your approach working by adding "AND f.time > subdate" with interval using 1 month difference to your "f.time <=" check for each line. 
Let's see if there will be other suggested solutions...

Comment: okay, seems like you are the only one to help here. 
Thank you, I accept your answer as I could use such approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the working query above which produced the results in the following way:

```
user1 ... 1st_period_4user1 action1 action2 action3 action4
user1 ... 2nd_period_4user1 action1 action2 action3 action4
```

I had the last 5 columns concatenated into "period+4 actions" string.
Then I had the table ranked so there would be 1 to 12 rankings there.
Then using the concatenated column as value and ranks as columns I pivot again...
Doing this 12 times:

```
array_agg(stf) FILTER (where rnk = 1) AS period_1
array_agg(stf) FILTER (where rnk = 2) AS period_2
```

to get user_id with 12 data columns.
**The drawback with this approach is that once a month is skipped it still is ranked as next period.**

Then I join additional info/organisations tables to add more to user_id.

This took 67 lines of code and 4 CTEs...
Still hope for a more refined solution...

This answer is posted for informational purposes only.